# Преобразование координат svg объекта, созданного в Inkscape для web-страницы

Tags: svg, inkscape

Есть несколько кнопок, нарисованных в `Inkscape`. Нарисованы они друг под другом.
При сохранении в `svg` образуются `path` с координатами `Inkscape`.
Для работы с `svg` использую `Snapsvg`. Загружая файл и отрисовывая отдельные кнопки, они рисуются как и в `Inkscape`, с такими же отступами.
Как этого избежать? Т.е. нужно как то преобразовать координаты всех кнопок, чтобы `path` начинался с (0,0)

Comment: вот здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/801156/28748 очень подробно, на примерах показано, как преобразовать патч к началу координат

Answer (score 3):

Для этой цели используется `viewBox`:

```
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="shape1">
```

`viewBox`, установленный в теге `<symbol>` определяет координаты конкретного элемента, где он находится и какой его размер:

```html
<svg style="display:none;">
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="shape1">
        <circle fill="blue" cx="10" cy="10" r="9"/> 
    </symbol>
    <symbol viewBox="100 100 10 10" id="shape2">
        <circle fill="green" cx="105" cy="105" r="4.5"/> 
    </symbol> 
</svg>
Два круга разных размеров и в разных местах с правильно настроенным viewBox выглядят одинаково:<br>
<svg width="35" height="35">
    <use xlink:href="#shape1" width="35" height="35" x="0" y="0" id="apis"></use>
</svg>
<svg width="35" height="35" >
    <use xlink:href="#shape2" width="35" height="35" x="0" y="0" id="apis"></use>
</svg>
```