# Как привести имеющуюся фигуру SVG к другим координатам

Tags: svg, редактор, inkscape

У меня есть фигура SVG, которую я получил из SVG редактора.

Как её перевести в координаты к началу координат нужного размера?

Сейчас чтобы её куда-то поместить приходится добавлять к `path` `transform="scale(...) translate(...)"` и величины сдвига и масштабирования приходится подбирать в ручную. И вообще после `scale` `translate` вообще в других величинах начинает работать.

Как нормально работать с такими фигурами и размещать их на полотне?

Что хотелось бы: какая-то утилита или функция которая переделывает координаты и размер `path`-а к началу координат и в необходимый размер.

```html
<svg style="width:400px; height:400px; background-color:pink">
  <path d="m53 297c0 0-1 0-1 0 0 0 0-3 0-7 0-6 0-10 1-12 0-1 1-1 2-1 1 0 2 1 3 2 0 1 0 5 0 9 0 2 0 4 0 5 0 2-1 3-2 4-1 1-1 1-3 0zm-24-5c-1 0-1-1-1-1 0-1 1-4 4-10 2-3 2-5 3-6 2-2 2-2 4 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 0 2-1 5-3 8-2 3-3 4-3 5 0 1-1 2-2 3-1 1-1 1-3 0zm46-3c-3-3-9-13-9-15 0-1 1-2 1-3 0 0 1 0 2-1 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 1 5 7 8 14l1 3-1 1c-1 1-3 2-3 2 0 0-1-1-2-1zm-65-16c-1 0-1-2-1-3 0-1 7-6 10-7 2-1 3-1 4-1 1 0 1 1 1 2 0 1 0 2 0 2 0 1-3 2-6 4-1 0-2 1-3 2-2 1-4 1-5 1zm86-2c-1 0-2 0-6-3-2-1-4-2-6-3-2-1-3-2-4-3-1-1-2-2-2-3 0-1 0-2 2-2 1 0 4 0 6 1 2 1 9 6 11 7 1 1 2 2 1 4-1 2-1 2-3 1zm-56-1c-2 0-5-1-6-2-3-2-5-5-7-8-3-5-4-14-2-19 2-7 9-15 15-19 2-1 5-2 6-2 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 4 0 5 0 1-1 2-4 5-7 6-8 9-9 14 0 2-1 4-1 5 0 2 1 6 3 8 5 7 13 8 24 2 3-2 5-4 9-10l2-3 0-3c0-3 0-4-1-5-1-2-3-3-5-4-1-1-2-1-4-1-2 0-3 0-5 1-3 1-6 3-7 6 0 1-1 1 0 3 0 2 1 4 2 5 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0-1-1-1-2-2-2-4-1-6 1-1 4-3 5-3 2 0 3 1 5 3 2 3 3 5 1 9-1 3-5 6-8 7-2 1-6 0-8 0-1 0-2-1-2-1-1 0-3-5-3-7-1-4 0-10 2-13 2-2 5-5 9-7 4-2 5-3 9-3 4 0 6 1 9 3 5 4 7 9 7 16 0 4 0 8-1 10-1 2-2 4-6 7-6 5-12 7-21 9-3 0-8 0-11 0zM5 248c-4 0-4-1-5-2-1-1-1-2 0-2 1-2 4-2 12-2 6 0 6 0 7 1 1 0 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 2-2 3-3 1-8 2-14 1zm80-1c-1-1-1-1-1-2 0-2 1-3 6-4 1 0 3-1 4-1 1 0 3-1 6-1 4 0 4 0 5 0 1 1 1 2 1 3-1 1-1 2-5 3-5 1-9 2-12 2-3 0-3 0-4 0zM19 230c-9-5-14-8-14-10 0-1 0-2 1-3 1 0 1 0 3 0 2 1 7 3 9 4 1 1 3 2 4 3 3 2 3 3 2 5-1 1-2 2-3 2 0 0-1-1-3-1zm58-2c-1 0-2-2-2-2 0-1 0-1 2-3 3-3 6-5 8-7 1-1 2-1 3-1 2 0 4 2 3 4-1 1-3 3-5 5-5 3-7 4-8 4zm-46-10c-2-2-4-5-5-9-1-3-1-3-1-5 0-3 0-4 2-4 1 0 2 1 2 1 0 0 1 2 3 5 3 5 4 7 4 10 0 2 0 2-2 3-1 0-1 0-2-1zm25 0c-1-1-2-2-2-3 0-1 1-10 1-12 1-3 2-5 4-6 1 0 2 0 2 2 1 2 1 7-2 18 0 0-1 1-1 1-2 1-1 1-2 0z" id="path826" style="fill:green;"/>
</svg>
```

Прокрутите пример ниже для того что бы увидеть фигуру.

Мне надо разместить эту фигуру на полотне так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как это можно сделать нормально?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Открыть в редакторе (исп. Inkscape) > выделить фигуру > Правка > Подогнать размер страницы до выделения (`Shift`+`Ctrl`+`R`) > сохранить > изъять из файла правильный `path` или привести в божеский вид новый файл.

```html
<svg style="width:400px; height:400px; background-color:pink">
 <path
     d="m 53.75,100 c 0,0 -1,0 -1,0 0,0 0,-3 0,-7 0,-6 0,-10 1,-12 0,-1 1,-1 2,-1 1,0 2,1 3,2 0,1 0,5 0,9 0,2 0,4 0,5 0,2 -1,3 -2,4 -1,1 -1,1 -3,0 z m -24,-5 c -1,0 -1,-1 -1,-1 0,-1 1,-4 4,-10 2,-3 2,-5 3,-6 2,-2 2,-2 4,0 1,1 1,1 1,2 0,2 -1,5 -3,8 -2,3 -3,4 -3,5 0,1 -1,2 -2,3 -1,1 -1,1 -3,0 z m 46,-3 c -3,-3 -9,-13 -9,-15 0,-1 1,-2 1,-3 0,0 1,0 2,-1 2,0 2,0 2,0 2,1 5,7 8,14 l 1,3 -1,1 c -1,1 -3,2 -3,2 0,0 -1,-1 -2,-1 z m -65,-16 c -1,0 -1,-2 -1,-3 0,-1 7,-6 10,-7 2,-1 3,-1 4,-1 1,0 1,1 1,2 0,1 0,2 0,2 0,1 -3,2 -6,4 -1,0 -2,1 -3,2 -2,1 -4,1 -5,1 z m 86,-2 c -1,0 -2,0 -6,-3 -2,-1 -4,-2 -6,-3 -2,-1 -3,-2 -4,-3 -1,-1 -2,-2 -2,-3 0,-1 0,-2 2,-2 1,0 4,0 6,1 2,1 9,6 11,7 1,1 2,2 1,4 -1,2 -1,2 -3,1 z m -56,-1 c -2,0 -5,-1 -6,-2 -3,-2 -5,-5 -7,-8 -3,-5 -4,-14 -2,-19 2,-7 9,-15 15,-19 2,-1 5,-2 6,-2 1,0 1,0 1,1 1,1 1,4 0,5 0,1 -1,2 -4,5 -7,6 -8,9 -9,14 0,2 -1,4 -1,5 0,2 1,6 3,8 5,7 13,8 24,2 3,-2 5,-4 9,-10 l 2,-3 v -3 c 0,-3 0,-4 -1,-5 -1,-2 -3,-3 -5,-4 -1,-1 -2,-1 -4,-1 -2,0 -3,0 -5,1 -3,1 -6,3 -7,6 0,1 -1,1 0,3 0,2 1,4 2,5 1,1 1,1 2,1 1,0 1,0 1,0 0,0 0,-1 -1,-1 -2,-2 -2,-4 -1,-6 1,-1 4,-3 5,-3 2,0 3,1 5,3 2,3 3,5 1,9 -1,3 -5,6 -8,7 -2,1 -6,0 -8,0 -1,0 -2,-1 -2,-1 -1,0 -3,-5 -3,-7 -1,-4 0,-10 2,-13 2,-2 5,-5 9,-7 4,-2 5,-3 9,-3 4,0 6,1 9,3 5,4 7,9 7,16 0,4 0,8 -1,10 -1,2 -2,4 -6,7 -6,5 -12,7 -21,9 -3,0 -8,0 -11,0 z m -35,-22 c -4,0 -4,-1 -5,-2 -1,-1 -1,-2 0,-2 1,-2 4,-2 12,-2 6,0 6,0 7,1 1,0 1,1 2,2 1,2 1,2 -2,3 -3,1 -8,2 -14,1 z m 80,-1 c -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-2 0,-2 1,-3 6,-4 1,0 3,-1 4,-1 1,0 3,-1 6,-1 4,0 4,0 5,0 1,1 1,2 1,3 -1,1 -1,2 -5,3 -5,1 -9,2 -12,2 -3,0 -3,0 -4,0 z m -66,-17 c -9,-5 -14,-8 -14,-10 0,-1 0,-2 1,-3 1,0 1,0 3,0 2,1 7,3 9,4 1,1 3,2 4,3 3,2 3,3 2,5 -1,1 -2,2 -3,2 0,0 -1,-1 -3,-1 z m 58,-2 c -1,0 -2,-2 -2,-2 0,-1 0,-1 2,-3 3,-3 6,-5 8,-7 1,-1 2,-1 3,-1 2,0 4,2 3,4 -1,1 -3,3 -5,5 -5,3 -7,4 -8,4 z m -46,-10 c -2,-2 -4,-5 -5,-9 -1,-3 -1,-3 -1,-5 0,-3 0,-4 2,-4 1,0 2,1 2,1 0,0 1,2 3,5 3,5 4,7 4,10 0,2 0,2 -2,3 -1,0 -1,0 -2,-1 z m 25,0 c -1,-1 -2,-2 -2,-3 0,-1 1,-10 1,-12 1,-3 2,-5 4,-6 1,0 2,0 2,2 1,2 1,7 -2,18 0,0 -1,1 -1,1 -2,1 -1,1 -2,0 z" id="path826" style="fill:#008000" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Ого, хороший вариант, хотя у меня не сразу получилось.

Answer (score 10):

### Корректировка позиционирования - существующего патча

- Загрузим файл svg в векторный редактор:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видимо в установках редактора размер документа был `100х100px` это черный квадрат по центру рисунка, а изображение было создано ниже поля документа.

- Расширяем размер документа - `400x400px` для того, чтобы рисунок был
  в зоне действия документа.

Для этого задаем `viewport` `width="400"`и `height="400"` `viewBox="0 0 400 400"` 
Красная рамка это границы svg документа, задана для наглядности в шапке svg файла `style="border:1px solid red;"`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" style="border:1px solid red;">
  <path d="m53 297c0 0-1 0-1 0 0 0 0-3 0-7 0-6 0-10 1-12 0-1 1-1 2-1 1 0 2 1 3 2 0 1 0 5 0 9 0 2 0 4 0 5 0 2-1 3-2 4-1 1-1 1-3 0zm-24-5c-1 0-1-1-1-1 0-1 1-4 4-10 2-3 2-5 3-6 2-2 2-2 4 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 0 2-1 5-3 8-2 3-3 4-3 5 0 1-1 2-2 3-1 1-1 1-3 0zm46-3c-3-3-9-13-9-15 0-1 1-2 1-3 0 0 1 0 2-1 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 1 5 7 8 14l1 3-1 1c-1 1-3 2-3 2 0 0-1-1-2-1zm-65-16c-1 0-1-2-1-3 0-1 7-6 10-7 2-1 3-1 4-1 1 0 1 1 1 2 0 1 0 2 0 2 0 1-3 2-6 4-1 0-2 1-3 2-2 1-4 1-5 1zm86-2c-1 0-2 0-6-3-2-1-4-2-6-3-2-1-3-2-4-3-1-1-2-2-2-3 0-1 0-2 2-2 1 0 4 0 6 1 2 1 9 6 11 7 1 1 2 2 1 4-1 2-1 2-3 1zm-56-1c-2 0-5-1-6-2-3-2-5-5-7-8-3-5-4-14-2-19 2-7 9-15 15-19 2-1 5-2 6-2 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 4 0 5 0 1-1 2-4 5-7 6-8 9-9 14 0 2-1 4-1 5 0 2 1 6 3 8 5 7 13 8 24 2 3-2 5-4 9-10l2-3 0-3c0-3 0-4-1-5-1-2-3-3-5-4-1-1-2-1-4-1-2 0-3 0-5 1-3 1-6 3-7 6 0 1-1 1 0 3 0 2 1 4 2 5 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0-1-1-1-2-2-2-4-1-6 1-1 4-3 5-3 2 0 3 1 5 3 2 3 3 5 1 9-1 3-5 6-8 7-2 1-6 0-8 0-1 0-2-1-2-1-1 0-3-5-3-7-1-4 0-10 2-13 2-2 5-5 9-7 4-2 5-3 9-3 4 0 6 1 9 3 5 4 7 9 7 16 0 4 0 8-1 10-1 2-2 4-6 7-6 5-12 7-21 9-3 0-8 0-11 0zM5 248c-4 0-4-1-5-2-1-1-1-2 0-2 1-2 4-2 12-2 6 0 6 0 7 1 1 0 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 2-2 3-3 1-8 2-14 1zm80-1c-1-1-1-1-1-2 0-2 1-3 6-4 1 0 3-1 4-1 1 0 3-1 6-1 4 0 4 0 5 0 1 1 1 2 1 3-1 1-1 2-5 3-5 1-9 2-12 2-3 0-3 0-4 0zM19 230c-9-5-14-8-14-10 0-1 0-2 1-3 1 0 1 0 3 0 2 1 7 3 9 4 1 1 3 2 4 3 3 2 3 3 2 5-1 1-2 2-3 2 0 0-1-1-3-1zm58-2c-1 0-2-2-2-2 0-1 0-1 2-3 3-3 6-5 8-7 1-1 2-1 3-1 2 0 4 2 3 4-1 1-3 3-5 5-5 3-7 4-8 4zm-46-10c-2-2-4-5-5-9-1-3-1-3-1-5 0-3 0-4 2-4 1 0 2 1 2 1 0 0 1 2 3 5 3 5 4 7 4 10 0 2 0 2-2 3-1 0-1 0-2-1zm25 0c-1-1-2-2-2-3 0-1 1-10 1-12 1-3 2-5 4-6 1 0 2 0 2 2 1 2 1 7-2 18 0 0-1 1-1 1-2 1-1 1-2 0z" id="path826" style="fill:green;"/>
</svg>
```

- Загружаем этот же файл в векторный редактор для наглядности

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Видим, что фигура попала в зону действия документа `400x400px` и её
  надо поднять на `196px` вверх, чтобы переместить в начало координат
  (4px оставляем, чтобы не обрезались сверху линии фигуры) 
  Для поднятия изменяем параметр  `min-y` для `viewBox`

`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 196 400 400">`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 196 400 400">
  <path d="m53 297c0 0-1 0-1 0 0 0 0-3 0-7 0-6 0-10 1-12 0-1 1-1 2-1 1 0 2 1 3 2 0 1 0 5 0 9 0 2 0 4 0 5 0 2-1 3-2 4-1 1-1 1-3 0zm-24-5c-1 0-1-1-1-1 0-1 1-4 4-10 2-3 2-5 3-6 2-2 2-2 4 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 0 2-1 5-3 8-2 3-3 4-3 5 0 1-1 2-2 3-1 1-1 1-3 0zm46-3c-3-3-9-13-9-15 0-1 1-2 1-3 0 0 1 0 2-1 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 1 5 7 8 14l1 3-1 1c-1 1-3 2-3 2 0 0-1-1-2-1zm-65-16c-1 0-1-2-1-3 0-1 7-6 10-7 2-1 3-1 4-1 1 0 1 1 1 2 0 1 0 2 0 2 0 1-3 2-6 4-1 0-2 1-3 2-2 1-4 1-5 1zm86-2c-1 0-2 0-6-3-2-1-4-2-6-3-2-1-3-2-4-3-1-1-2-2-2-3 0-1 0-2 2-2 1 0 4 0 6 1 2 1 9 6 11 7 1 1 2 2 1 4-1 2-1 2-3 1zm-56-1c-2 0-5-1-6-2-3-2-5-5-7-8-3-5-4-14-2-19 2-7 9-15 15-19 2-1 5-2 6-2 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 4 0 5 0 1-1 2-4 5-7 6-8 9-9 14 0 2-1 4-1 5 0 2 1 6 3 8 5 7 13 8 24 2 3-2 5-4 9-10l2-3 0-3c0-3 0-4-1-5-1-2-3-3-5-4-1-1-2-1-4-1-2 0-3 0-5 1-3 1-6 3-7 6 0 1-1 1 0 3 0 2 1 4 2 5 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0-1-1-1-2-2-2-4-1-6 1-1 4-3 5-3 2 0 3 1 5 3 2 3 3 5 1 9-1 3-5 6-8 7-2 1-6 0-8 0-1 0-2-1-2-1-1 0-3-5-3-7-1-4 0-10 2-13 2-2 5-5 9-7 4-2 5-3 9-3 4 0 6 1 9 3 5 4 7 9 7 16 0 4 0 8-1 10-1 2-2 4-6 7-6 5-12 7-21 9-3 0-8 0-11 0zM5 248c-4 0-4-1-5-2-1-1-1-2 0-2 1-2 4-2 12-2 6 0 6 0 7 1 1 0 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 2-2 3-3 1-8 2-14 1zm80-1c-1-1-1-1-1-2 0-2 1-3 6-4 1 0 3-1 4-1 1 0 3-1 6-1 4 0 4 0 5 0 1 1 1 2 1 3-1 1-1 2-5 3-5 1-9 2-12 2-3 0-3 0-4 0zM19 230c-9-5-14-8-14-10 0-1 0-2 1-3 1 0 1 0 3 0 2 1 7 3 9 4 1 1 3 2 4 3 3 2 3 3 2 5-1 1-2 2-3 2 0 0-1-1-3-1zm58-2c-1 0-2-2-2-2 0-1 0-1 2-3 3-3 6-5 8-7 1-1 2-1 3-1 2 0 4 2 3 4-1 1-3 3-5 5-5 3-7 4-8 4zm-46-10c-2-2-4-5-5-9-1-3-1-3-1-5 0-3 0-4 2-4 1 0 2 1 2 1 0 0 1 2 3 5 3 5 4 7 4 10 0 2 0 2-2 3-1 0-1 0-2-1zm25 0c-1-1-2-2-2-3 0-1 1-10 1-12 1-3 2-5 4-6 1 0 2 0 2 2 1 2 1 7-2 18 0 0-1 1-1 1-2 1-1 1-2 0z" id="path826" style="fill:green;"/>
</svg>
```

- Снова проверяем в векторном редакторе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видим, что фигура расположена как надо, но документ svg слишком большой, поэтому надо уменьшить его размеры

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100" height="200" viewBox="0 196 100 200">
  <path d="m53 297c0 0-1 0-1 0 0 0 0-3 0-7 0-6 0-10 1-12 0-1 1-1 2-1 1 0 2 1 3 2 0 1 0 5 0 9 0 2 0 4 0 5 0 2-1 3-2 4-1 1-1 1-3 0zm-24-5c-1 0-1-1-1-1 0-1 1-4 4-10 2-3 2-5 3-6 2-2 2-2 4 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 0 2-1 5-3 8-2 3-3 4-3 5 0 1-1 2-2 3-1 1-1 1-3 0zm46-3c-3-3-9-13-9-15 0-1 1-2 1-3 0 0 1 0 2-1 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 1 5 7 8 14l1 3-1 1c-1 1-3 2-3 2 0 0-1-1-2-1zm-65-16c-1 0-1-2-1-3 0-1 7-6 10-7 2-1 3-1 4-1 1 0 1 1 1 2 0 1 0 2 0 2 0 1-3 2-6 4-1 0-2 1-3 2-2 1-4 1-5 1zm86-2c-1 0-2 0-6-3-2-1-4-2-6-3-2-1-3-2-4-3-1-1-2-2-2-3 0-1 0-2 2-2 1 0 4 0 6 1 2 1 9 6 11 7 1 1 2 2 1 4-1 2-1 2-3 1zm-56-1c-2 0-5-1-6-2-3-2-5-5-7-8-3-5-4-14-2-19 2-7 9-15 15-19 2-1 5-2 6-2 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 4 0 5 0 1-1 2-4 5-7 6-8 9-9 14 0 2-1 4-1 5 0 2 1 6 3 8 5 7 13 8 24 2 3-2 5-4 9-10l2-3 0-3c0-3 0-4-1-5-1-2-3-3-5-4-1-1-2-1-4-1-2 0-3 0-5 1-3 1-6 3-7 6 0 1-1 1 0 3 0 2 1 4 2 5 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0-1-1-1-2-2-2-4-1-6 1-1 4-3 5-3 2 0 3 1 5 3 2 3 3 5 1 9-1 3-5 6-8 7-2 1-6 0-8 0-1 0-2-1-2-1-1 0-3-5-3-7-1-4 0-10 2-13 2-2 5-5 9-7 4-2 5-3 9-3 4 0 6 1 9 3 5 4 7 9 7 16 0 4 0 8-1 10-1 2-2 4-6 7-6 5-12 7-21 9-3 0-8 0-11 0zM5 248c-4 0-4-1-5-2-1-1-1-2 0-2 1-2 4-2 12-2 6 0 6 0 7 1 1 0 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 2-2 3-3 1-8 2-14 1zm80-1c-1-1-1-1-1-2 0-2 1-3 6-4 1 0 3-1 4-1 1 0 3-1 6-1 4 0 4 0 5 0 1 1 1 2 1 3-1 1-1 2-5 3-5 1-9 2-12 2-3 0-3 0-4 0zM19 230c-9-5-14-8-14-10 0-1 0-2 1-3 1 0 1 0 3 0 2 1 7 3 9 4 1 1 3 2 4 3 3 2 3 3 2 5-1 1-2 2-3 2 0 0-1-1-3-1zm58-2c-1 0-2-2-2-2 0-1 0-1 2-3 3-3 6-5 8-7 1-1 2-1 3-1 2 0 4 2 3 4-1 1-3 3-5 5-5 3-7 4-8 4zm-46-10c-2-2-4-5-5-9-1-3-1-3-1-5 0-3 0-4 2-4 1 0 2 1 2 1 0 0 1 2 3 5 3 5 4 7 4 10 0 2 0 2-2 3-1 0-1 0-2-1zm25 0c-1-1-2-2-2-3 0-1 1-10 1-12 1-3 2-5 4-6 1 0 2 0 2 2 1 2 1 7-2 18 0 0-1 1-1 1-2 1-1 1-2 0z" id="path826" style="fill:green;"/>
</svg>
```

*Такие действия по корректировке нужны, когда картинка svg сложная, чужая и нет возможности перерисовать изначально правильно.*

### Как правильно делать?

Допустим вам нужно нарисовать лого с размерами `100x100px`

Для этого, вы либо в векторном редакторе устанавливаете нужный размер документа, либо пишите коротенький файл-шаблон и загружаете в векторный редактор.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="border:1px solid red;">
</svg>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Рисуем в векторном редакторе строго внутри границ документа

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Сохраняем файл и проверяем его в броузере

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" >
  <metadata id="metadata8"/>
  <defs id="defs6"/>
  <path id="path4177" d="m59 59c-4 5-13 5-18 1-6-5-6-15-1-21 6-7 18-7 25-1 8 7 8 21 1 29-9 10-24 10-34 1C21 58 21 40 31 29 43 16 63 16 76 28 91 42 91 65 78 80 62 97 35 97 18 82-1 64-1 33 16 14 20 10 23 7 27 5" style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#008000;stroke:#000"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 9):

На днях нашёл интересный инструмент ([ссылка](http://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg_transforms)). Нужно лишь вставить отдельный элемент, в данном случае `path`, а затем выбрать тип - `absolute`:

```html
<svg style="width:400px; height:400px; background-color:pink">
  <path d="M53 99C53 99 52 99 52 99 52 99 52 96 52 92 52 86 52 82 53 80 53 79 54 79 55 79 56 79 57 80 58 81 58 82 58 86 58 90 58 92 58 94 58 95 58 97 57 98 56 99 55 100 55 100 53 99zM29 94C28 94 28 93 28 93 28 92 29 89 32 83 34 80 34 78 35 77 37 75 37 75 39 77 40 78 40 78 40 79 40 81 39 84 37 87 35 90 34 91 34 92 34 93 33 94 32 95 31 96 31 96 29 95zM75 92C72 89 66 79 66 77 66 76 67 75 67 74 67 74 68 74 69 73 71 73 71 73 71 73 73 74 76 80 79 87L80 90 79 91C78 92 76 93 76 93 76 93 75 92 74 92zM9 76C8 76 8 74 8 73 8 72 15 67 18 66 20 65 21 65 22 65 23 65 23 66 23 67 23 68 23 69 23 69 23 70 20 71 17 73 16 73 15 74 14 75 12 76 10 76 9 76zM95 74C94 74 93 74 89 71 87 70 85 69 83 68 81 67 80 66 79 65 78 64 77 63 77 62 77 61 77 60 79 60 80 60 83 60 85 61 87 62 94 67 96 68 97 69 98 70 97 72 96 74 96 74 94 73zM38 72C36 72 33 71 32 70 29 68 27 65 25 62 22 57 21 48 23 43 25 36 32 28 38 24 40 23 43 22 44 22 45 22 45 22 45 23 46 24 46 27 45 28 45 29 44 30 41 33 34 39 33 42 32 47 32 49 31 51 31 52 31 54 32 58 34 60 39 67 47 68 58 62 61 60 63 58 67 52L69 49 69 46C69 43 69 42 68 41 67 39 65 38 63 37 62 36 61 36 59 36 57 36 56 36 54 37 51 38 48 40 47 43 47 44 46 44 47 46 47 48 48 50 49 51 50 52 50 52 51 52 52 52 52 52 52 52 52 52 52 51 51 51 49 49 49 47 50 45 51 44 54 42 55 42 57 42 58 43 60 45 62 48 63 50 61 54 60 57 56 60 53 61 51 62 47 61 45 61 44 61 43 60 43 60 42 60 40 55 40 53 39 49 40 43 42 40 44 38 47 35 51 33 55 31 56 30 60 30 64 30 66 31 69 33 74 37 76 42 76 49 76 53 76 57 75 59 74 61 73 63 69 66 63 71 57 73 48 75 45 75 40 75 37 75zM5 50C1 50 1 49 0 48 -1 47 -1 46 0 46 1 44 4 44 12 44 18 44 18 44 19 45 20 45 20 46 21 47 22 49 22 49 19 50 16 51 11 52 5 51zM85 50C84 49 84 49 84 48 84 46 85 45 90 44 91 44 93 43 94 43 95 43 97 42 100 42 104 42 104 42 105 42 106 43 106 44 106 45 105 46 105 47 101 48 96 49 92 50 89 50 86 50 86 50 85 50zM19 32C10 27 5 24 5 22 5 21 5 20 6 19 7 19 7 19 9 19 11 20 16 22 18 23 19 24 21 25 22 26 25 28 25 29 24 31 23 32 22 33 21 33 21 33 20 32 18 32zM76 30C75 30 74 28 74 28 74 27 74 27 76 25 79 22 82 20 84 18 85 17 86 17 87 17 89 17 91 19 90 21 89 22 87 24 85 26 80 29 78 30 77 30zM31 20C29 18 27 15 26 11 25 8 25 8 25 6 25 3 25 2 27 2 28 2 29 3 29 3 29 3 30 5 32 8 35 13 36 15 36 18 36 20 36 20 34 21 33 21 33 21 32 20zM57 20C56 19 55 18 55 17 55 16 56 7 56 5 57 2 58 0 60 -1 61 -1 62 -1 62 1 63 3 63 8 60 19 60 19 59 20 59 20 57 21 58 21 57 20z" id="path826" style="fill:green;"/>
</svg>
```

**Добавлено Дмитрием**

Для определения насколько надо перенести использую функцию `getBBox()`.

Из неё легко можно найти координаты для переноса.

```js
var bbox = document.getElementById("id1").getBBox();

console.log(bbox);
```

```html
<svg style="width:400px; height:400px; background-color:pink">
  <path id="id1" d="m53 297c0 0-1 0-1 0 0 0 0-3 0-7 0-6 0-10 1-12 0-1 1-1 2-1 1 0 2 1 3 2 0 1 0 5 0 9 0 2 0 4 0 5 0 2-1 3-2 4-1 1-1 1-3 0zm-24-5c-1 0-1-1-1-1 0-1 1-4 4-10 2-3 2-5 3-6 2-2 2-2 4 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 0 2-1 5-3 8-2 3-3 4-3 5 0 1-1 2-2 3-1 1-1 1-3 0zm46-3c-3-3-9-13-9-15 0-1 1-2 1-3 0 0 1 0 2-1 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 1 5 7 8 14l1 3-1 1c-1 1-3 2-3 2 0 0-1-1-2-1zm-65-16c-1 0-1-2-1-3 0-1 7-6 10-7 2-1 3-1 4-1 1 0 1 1 1 2 0 1 0 2 0 2 0 1-3 2-6 4-1 0-2 1-3 2-2 1-4 1-5 1zm86-2c-1 0-2 0-6-3-2-1-4-2-6-3-2-1-3-2-4-3-1-1-2-2-2-3 0-1 0-2 2-2 1 0 4 0 6 1 2 1 9 6 11 7 1 1 2 2 1 4-1 2-1 2-3 1zm-56-1c-2 0-5-1-6-2-3-2-5-5-7-8-3-5-4-14-2-19 2-7 9-15 15-19 2-1 5-2 6-2 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 4 0 5 0 1-1 2-4 5-7 6-8 9-9 14 0 2-1 4-1 5 0 2 1 6 3 8 5 7 13 8 24 2 3-2 5-4 9-10l2-3 0-3c0-3 0-4-1-5-1-2-3-3-5-4-1-1-2-1-4-1-2 0-3 0-5 1-3 1-6 3-7 6 0 1-1 1 0 3 0 2 1 4 2 5 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0-1-1-1-2-2-2-4-1-6 1-1 4-3 5-3 2 0 3 1 5 3 2 3 3 5 1 9-1 3-5 6-8 7-2 1-6 0-8 0-1 0-2-1-2-1-1 0-3-5-3-7-1-4 0-10 2-13 2-2 5-5 9-7 4-2 5-3 9-3 4 0 6 1 9 3 5 4 7 9 7 16 0 4 0 8-1 10-1 2-2 4-6 7-6 5-12 7-21 9-3 0-8 0-11 0zM5 248c-4 0-4-1-5-2-1-1-1-2 0-2 1-2 4-2 12-2 6 0 6 0 7 1 1 0 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 2-2 3-3 1-8 2-14 1zm80-1c-1-1-1-1-1-2 0-2 1-3 6-4 1 0 3-1 4-1 1 0 3-1 6-1 4 0 4 0 5 0 1 1 1 2 1 3-1 1-1 2-5 3-5 1-9 2-12 2-3 0-3 0-4 0zM19 230c-9-5-14-8-14-10 0-1 0-2 1-3 1 0 1 0 3 0 2 1 7 3 9 4 1 1 3 2 4 3 3 2 3 3 2 5-1 1-2 2-3 2 0 0-1-1-3-1zm58-2c-1 0-2-2-2-2 0-1 0-1 2-3 3-3 6-5 8-7 1-1 2-1 3-1 2 0 4 2 3 4-1 1-3 3-5 5-5 3-7 4-8 4zm-46-10c-2-2-4-5-5-9-1-3-1-3-1-5 0-3 0-4 2-4 1 0 2 1 2 1 0 0 1 2 3 5 3 5 4 7 4 10 0 2 0 2-2 3-1 0-1 0-2-1zm25 0c-1-1-2-2-2-3 0-1 1-10 1-12 1-3 2-5 4-6 1 0 2 0 2 2 1 2 1 7-2 18 0 0-1 1-1 1-2 1-1 1-2 0z" id="path826" style="fill:green;"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Похожий вопрос на enSO - https://stackoverflow.com/a/16286776/9464680

Comment: Какой увлекательный скрипт по ссылке. Надо будет с ним разобраться! Благо дарю!

Answer (score 1):

Необязательно редактировать svg в редакторе, чтобы обрезать область рендеринга svg. Для этого есть поддерживаемый всеми аттрибут `viewBox`. SVG скопирована прямо из вашего вопроса, но добавлен аттрибут:

```html
<svg style="width:400px; height:400px; background-color:pink" viewBox="-2 199 110 98">
  <path d="m53 297c0 0-1 0-1 0 0 0 0-3 0-7 0-6 0-10 1-12 0-1 1-1 2-1 1 0 2 1 3 2 0 1 0 5 0 9 0 2 0 4 0 5 0 2-1 3-2 4-1 1-1 1-3 0zm-24-5c-1 0-1-1-1-1 0-1 1-4 4-10 2-3 2-5 3-6 2-2 2-2 4 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 0 2-1 5-3 8-2 3-3 4-3 5 0 1-1 2-2 3-1 1-1 1-3 0zm46-3c-3-3-9-13-9-15 0-1 1-2 1-3 0 0 1 0 2-1 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 1 5 7 8 14l1 3-1 1c-1 1-3 2-3 2 0 0-1-1-2-1zm-65-16c-1 0-1-2-1-3 0-1 7-6 10-7 2-1 3-1 4-1 1 0 1 1 1 2 0 1 0 2 0 2 0 1-3 2-6 4-1 0-2 1-3 2-2 1-4 1-5 1zm86-2c-1 0-2 0-6-3-2-1-4-2-6-3-2-1-3-2-4-3-1-1-2-2-2-3 0-1 0-2 2-2 1 0 4 0 6 1 2 1 9 6 11 7 1 1 2 2 1 4-1 2-1 2-3 1zm-56-1c-2 0-5-1-6-2-3-2-5-5-7-8-3-5-4-14-2-19 2-7 9-15 15-19 2-1 5-2 6-2 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 4 0 5 0 1-1 2-4 5-7 6-8 9-9 14 0 2-1 4-1 5 0 2 1 6 3 8 5 7 13 8 24 2 3-2 5-4 9-10l2-3 0-3c0-3 0-4-1-5-1-2-3-3-5-4-1-1-2-1-4-1-2 0-3 0-5 1-3 1-6 3-7 6 0 1-1 1 0 3 0 2 1 4 2 5 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0-1-1-1-2-2-2-4-1-6 1-1 4-3 5-3 2 0 3 1 5 3 2 3 3 5 1 9-1 3-5 6-8 7-2 1-6 0-8 0-1 0-2-1-2-1-1 0-3-5-3-7-1-4 0-10 2-13 2-2 5-5 9-7 4-2 5-3 9-3 4 0 6 1 9 3 5 4 7 9 7 16 0 4 0 8-1 10-1 2-2 4-6 7-6 5-12 7-21 9-3 0-8 0-11 0zM5 248c-4 0-4-1-5-2-1-1-1-2 0-2 1-2 4-2 12-2 6 0 6 0 7 1 1 0 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 2-2 3-3 1-8 2-14 1zm80-1c-1-1-1-1-1-2 0-2 1-3 6-4 1 0 3-1 4-1 1 0 3-1 6-1 4 0 4 0 5 0 1 1 1 2 1 3-1 1-1 2-5 3-5 1-9 2-12 2-3 0-3 0-4 0zM19 230c-9-5-14-8-14-10 0-1 0-2 1-3 1 0 1 0 3 0 2 1 7 3 9 4 1 1 3 2 4 3 3 2 3 3 2 5-1 1-2 2-3 2 0 0-1-1-3-1zm58-2c-1 0-2-2-2-2 0-1 0-1 2-3 3-3 6-5 8-7 1-1 2-1 3-1 2 0 4 2 3 4-1 1-3 3-5 5-5 3-7 4-8 4zm-46-10c-2-2-4-5-5-9-1-3-1-3-1-5 0-3 0-4 2-4 1 0 2 1 2 1 0 0 1 2 3 5 3 5 4 7 4 10 0 2 0 2-2 3-1 0-1 0-2-1zm25 0c-1-1-2-2-2-3 0-1 1-10 1-12 1-3 2-5 4-6 1 0 2 0 2 2 1 2 1 7-2 18 0 0-1 1-1 1-2 1-1 1-2 0z" id="path826" style="fill:green;"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: вы не поняли суть предыдущих ответов, чтобы написать `viewBox="-2 199 110 98"` надо хорошо понимать, как работают атрибуты viewBox. Поэтому буквально на пальцах, через картинки редактора было показано, где находится изображение, куда его надо двигать. И редактор был лишь визуальной проверкой, а оптимизация шла через фомулы svg

Comment: @Alexandr_TT я ценю ваш труд по ответу - он будет полезен людям. Но когда в сообществе программистов дают ответы, поясняющие как пользоваться графическими редакторами, и ни одного ответа - как сделать это в коде: это странновато. Хотя автор спросил автоматическую функцию обрезки: этого я не дал, но дал наводку - что необязательно вообще сдвигать координаты path

Comment: ну привел бы я ответ, как вы viewBox="-2 199 110 98"  для меня и других, кто хоть немного понимает svg это не составляет труда. Но это затычка на один раз. Я встречал сотни аналогичных вопросов на enSO и десятки здесь, где люди даже зная, что нужно менять параметры viewBox, тыкаются вслепую, подбирая значения и не получают результата

Comment: и опять вы невнимательно прочли мой ответ. Я там использовал граф. редактор только для визуального контроля, а делал все манипуляции формулами svg/ И вы наверное отвечая на вопрос, глянули на мою картинку, что надо поднять 200px и выставили -199px

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое решение, которое я нашёл с использованием `Inkscape`.

Уже есть подобный ответ, но добавляю инструкцию с картинками.

1. Выделяем мышкой объект который надо поместить в начало координат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Делаем `Resize to page selection`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Получаем изображение в начале координат и холст в размер изображения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: есть ещё одна манипуляция - её не добавляет не inkscape не illustrator не corel draw